# Why is UISwipeActionsConfiguration icon out of screen bounds?

Tags: swift

The icon of the swipe action even when i discarded one, the last stacked action is always out of the screen bounds.
here is my code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {

    let leavedetails = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "LEAVE") { (action, view, nil) in
        print("leave details")
        self.setView(view: self.floatView)
    }


    leavedetails.image = UIImage(named: "leavedetails")
    leavedetails.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

    let approved = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "APPROVE") { (action, view, nil) in
        print("approved")
    }


    approved.image = UIImage(named: "accept")
    approved.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    let reject = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "REJECT") { (action, view, nil) in
        print("reject")
    }
    reject.image = UIImage(named: "reject")
    reject.backgroundColor = UIColor.red


   let config = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [approved, leavedetails])
    config.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false
    return config
}
```

link to picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAjMr.png .

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have access to the images that you used, so used two random images. And, as shown in the screenshot, the image isn't out of bounds. Therefore, I believe you should double check the dimensions of your image.

### [image: Heading]